# Deploying Angular 4 app

Tags: angular

am using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxV3weqMzYo this video for deploying my angular 2 app in live but its gives below error

```
D:\selva\backup\ticketing>ngh
An error occurred!
 Error: Unspecified error (run without silent option for detail)
    at C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_
modules\gh-pages\lib\index.js:232:19
    at _rejected (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-gh
pages\node_modules\q\q.js:844:24)
    at C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_
modules\q\q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli
-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:788:41)
    at C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_
modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-gh
pages\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpage
s\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

please help me to rectify this error

**expected behavior**: deploying ticketing project to github pages

steps which i did

step 1: ng-build --prod

step 2: pushed all files to github including node_modules and dist folder

Here i have cleared all data's in ".gitignore" file to upload all project data to github account (including node_modules and dist folder)

step 3: ng-build --prod --base-href  https://selva1990kumar.github.io/ticketing/

step 4:ngh

IT PRODUCE THIS ERROR

```
An error occurred!
 Error: Unspecified error (run without silent option for detail)
    at C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_
modules\gh-pages\lib\index.js:232:19
    at _rejected (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-gh
pages\node_modules\q\q.js:844:24)
    at C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_
modules\q\q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli
-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:788:41)
    at C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_
modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-gh
pages\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpage
s\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @georgeawg : you can find my code here  https://github.com/selva1990kumar/ticketing

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg:is the extra details in question field is enof to reproduce the same error?

Comment: thingh is i have tried to deploy this project to github pages please check last part of code edited recently

Comment: I am facing the same issue.Can you please describe your solution

Comment: @RamandeepKaur : found answer by myself : you have to mention href value like this  <base href="https://yourgithubname.github.io/projectname/docs">    Here i have placed my dist folder as docs in github account

Comment: @RamandeepKaur : once u mentioned like that you don't need ngh and all Idea is very simple github pages just look for index.html file in the path which you have mentioned  PATH (href="yourgithubname.github.io/projectname/docs)

Comment: I have made changes as you described but not working. I have change the href path as you describe.ngh return successfully published.

Comment: @ Ramamdeep Kaur :Have you selected source on your github project settings page ?? If not please refer the image which i have posted last in my question and select the source in settings page of your github project Ram

Comment: ngh --no-silent use this to get detailed info

Answer (score 6):

First of all run this to get detailed info

> ngh --no-silent

Then if you get an error like this

```
message: '\n*** Please tell me who you are
```

Just Run :

> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

And This :

> git config --global user.name "Github User Name"

And Finally :

> ngh

[Check Here For More Info](https://github.com/blinks32/ionic5-taxi-complete-uber-and-lyft-clone-with-administrator)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.

Solved by command:

```
sudo ngh
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran

```
sudo ngh --dir dist/[PROJECT-NAME]
```

Hope that helps